# Get error when run application with flutter but on android part application is ok

Tags: flutter, android-studio, flutter-plugin

I am writing a Flutter plugin, On android part after finishing everything when I am running Android plugin with Android Studio, the plugin works correctly but when I am running my plugin on Flutter I got this error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeLibDexDebug'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform classes.jar (project :flutter_basis_theory) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr=7.3.0, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr=debug, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=21, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.jvm.environment=android, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime, org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type=androidJvm}.
      > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
         > No variants of javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.1.1 match the consumer attributes:
             - javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.1.1 configuration runtime declares a component for use during runtime:
                 - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'artifactType' with value '${packaging.type}' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'artifactType' with value 'android-classes-jar'
                 - Other compatible attributes:
                     - Doesn't say anything about asm-transformed-variant (required 'NONE')
                     - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '7.3.0')
                     - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'debug')
                     - Doesn't say anything about dexing-enable-desugaring (required 'true')
                     - Doesn't say anything about dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation (required 'false')
                     - Doesn't say anything about dexing-is-debuggable (required 'true')
                     - Doesn't say anything about dexing-min-sdk (required '21')
                     - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
                     - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type (required 'androidJvm')
   > Failed to transform classes.jar (project :integration_test) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr=7.3.0, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr=debug, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=21, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
         > No variants of javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.1.1 match the consumer attributes:
             - javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.1.1 configuration runtime declares a component for use during runtime:
                 - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'artifactType' with value '${packaging.type}' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'artifactType' with value 'android-classes-jar'
                 - Other compatible attributes:
                     - Doesn't say anything about asm-transformed-variant (required 'NONE')
                     - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '7.3.0')
                     - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'debug')
                     - Doesn't say anything about dexing-enable-desugaring (required 'true')
                     - Doesn't say anything about dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation (required 'false')
                     - Doesn't say anything about dexing-is-debuggable (required 'true')
                     - Doesn't say anything about dexing-min-sdk (required '21')
                     - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
                     - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type (required 'androidJvm')

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
```

this is my project build Gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My build gradle module app

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "kotlin-kapt"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    namespace "mypackagename_example"
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '17'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    defaultConfig {

        applicationId mypackagename_example
        
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {

            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {

}
```

and my plugin build gradle:

```
group 'mypackagename'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    if (project.android.hasProperty("namespace")) {
        namespace 'mypackagename'
    }

    compileSdk 33

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '17'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
        test.java.srcDirs += 'src/test/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk 21

    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'com.wajahatkarim:EasyFlipView:3.0.3'
        implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
        implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.1'
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
        implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.5.3'
        implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.1'
        implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.5.1'
        implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10.1'
        implementation 'com.github.basis-theory:basistheory-android:3.2.0'
        implementation('com.github.basis-theory:basistheory-java:1.1.0') {
            exclude group: 'javax.ws.rs', module: 'javax.ws.rs-api'
        }
        implementation 'org.threeten:threetenbp:1.6.8'
        testImplementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test'
        testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:5.0.0'
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests.all {
            useJUnitPlatform()

            testLogging {
               events "passed", "skipped", "failed", "standardOut", "standardError"
               outputs.upToDateWhen {false}
               showStandardStreams = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```